# Create a gst pad from a static pad template [GStreamer pipeline]

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Hi I am trying to create a streamer pad from a static pad template.

so far,

1. I've created a sink factory with the right element name
    `sink_factory = gst_element_factory_find("elementName");`
2. I've retrieved a list of static pad templates (from `gst_element_factory_get_static_pad_templates`), Based on direction and presence I've found the pad (static template) from the list and saved in a variable (`GstStaticPadTemplate *padtemplate`)

From the static pad template now I want to create a pad template, and I found this function

```
GstPadTemplate *
gst_pad_template_new_from_static_pad_template_with_gtype (GstStaticPadTemplate * pad_template,
                                                          GType pad_type)
```

which I'm planning to use with `gst_element_request_pad` like below

```
GstPad *
gst_element_request_pad (GstElement * element,
                         GstPadTemplate * templ,
                         const gchar * name,
                         const GstCaps * caps)
```

my question is I'm not really sure what to do with `GType pad_type`. I can't find any application to figure this out.

Cheers,
Ganindu.

P.S.

I know about `gst_element_request_pad_simple` and `gst_element_get_request_pad`

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
 GType pad_type;
 pad_type = GST_TYPE_PAD;
```

Context:
I just looked up the [source](https://git.io/JEOX1) and found this assertion

```
  g_return_val_if_fail (g_type_is_a (pad_type, GST_TYPE_PAD), NULL);
```